# How System.in of type InputStream is initialized?

Tags: java

I know that, in java, abstract class can only be referenced but not initialized. `InputStream` is an abstract class, and in the `System` class I noticed the following declaration,

```
static InputStream in;
```

So if we want the code `System.in.read()` to work, variable `in` needs to be initialized.

My question is how java does that? If `InputStream` is abstract, some other subclass should have extend it. Which class is that by default?

Comment: It could well be in a place that you don't have the source code for - either in an internal class (somewhere inside a sun. package) or inside the JVM itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Luckily, it is easy to check the type of object `System.in` refers to:

```
System.out.println(System.in.getClass().getName());
```

prints ( for me ):

```
java.io.BufferedInputStream
```

so it's a `BufferedInputStream`. What is it wrapping? Well,

```
Field field = FilterInputStream.class.getDeclaredField("in");
field.setAccessible(true);   
System.out.println(field.get(System.in).getClass().getName());
```

prints (again, for me):

```
java.io.FileInputStream
```

So `System.in` is a `FileInputStream` wrapped in a `BufferedInputStream`. This makes sense, if you consider that most operating systems treat the console the same way as a file. In fact, this `FileInputStream` reads from the "file" referred to by [`FileDescriptor.in`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html#in).

By searching for references to `FileDescriptor.in`, I found the code where System.in is initialized: in the private static method `System.initializeSystemClass`:

```
FileInputStream fdIn = new FileInputStream(FileDescriptor.in);
FileOutputStream fdOut = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out);
FileOutputStream fdErr = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.err);
setIn0(new BufferedInputStream(fdIn));
setOut0(newPrintStream(fdOut, props.getProperty("sun.stdout.encoding")));
setErr0(newPrintStream(fdErr, props.getProperty("sun.stderr.encoding")));
```

`initializeSystemClass` is probably called by native code, as there seem to be no references to it.

Comment: You have my gratitude.

Comment: It is called in `JvmtiExport::post_vm_start`, in `(hotspot) src/share/vm/runtime/thread.cpp`.

Answer (score 4):

There is some black magic that happens behind the scenes during JVM bootstrap to initialize `in` to the correct value.

For example, in Java 8 it is done by a private method called `initializeSystemClass()`.  The javadoc comment says:

> "Initialize the system class. Called after thread initialization."

Read the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/System.java#System.initializeSystemClass%28%29) for the gory details.  They could vary from one Java version to the next ... though they don't appear to have changed between Java 6 and Java 8.

Notes:

1. The actual setting of `System.in,out,err` is done by `native` methods.  These native methods are also used by the `System.set{In,Out,Err}` methods.
2. In Java 6 through Java 8, the `in` field is initialized to a `BufferedInputStream` that wraps a `FileInputStream`.  Interestingly, the input stream is typically not for a "file" ... in the sense of an object in the / a file system.

Answer (score -1):

The declaration in the `System` class is the following:

```
public final static InputStream in = null;
```

Please take a look at the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in):

> The "standard" input stream. This stream is already open and ready to
>   supply input data. Typically this stream corresponds to keyboard input
>   or another input source specified by the host environment or user.

It means that System.in is initialized by the Java runtime when a JVM starts up. Regarding your question:

> If InputStream is abstract, some other subclass should have extend it.
>   Which class is that by default?

Many classes extends the `InputStream` class, like: [FileInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html), [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html), ...